# How do I make a JavaScript call to a WCF service hosted on a different domain?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wcf, xmlhttprequest, wcf-routing

We are designing a web application using ASP.NET and AJAX and we want to host our WCF Service Layer on a different website and make JavaScript calls to the Service Layer from our client pages.  We understand that the browser will not allow AJAX calls to a different port or domain.  What is the best way to architect a solution?  We are considering using a proxy layer with services hosted on the same domain as the client which has a web reference to the service layer.  Is there a better solution?

Comment: The solution you propose is really the only way, I believe.

Answer (score 6):

It's generally best to limit the number of domains accessed by your page.  A server-side proxy is really a good way to go.

Answer (score 1):

i think the best way is to call a local Page which call remote resource and returns result. in this way, you avoid cross domains problems

Answer (score 0):

- You can do virtual hosting of the
  service and website under same
  domain but different folder.
- define the services in different
  dlls and create svc files in your
  websites and point the svc files to
  the dll which has the services
- server side proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Your load balancer could send all request to /service to your service server.

If you don't have a load balancer, you can have your webserver act as a reverse proxy to your service server.  If you are using IIS7, you can do this with the [Application Request Routing module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/489/using-the-application-request-routing-module).

Answer (score 0):

Prototype has a plug in for this.  The issue is on the client not the server.  www.mellowmorning.com/2007/10/25/introducing-a-cross-site-ajax-plugin-for-prototype/